# Nuxt3 different builds for different environments

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

Is it possible to specify for the Nuxt3 build/generate command an environment (or simply a destination folder) depending on the environment for which I am building (dev/test/pre/prod)?

Comment: I solved this by creating a post-script that copies the .output folder in a different env folder based on an env parameter passed along build command